# Correct way to merge craft.user field arrays and use outside the loop?

Tags: field, tags, forloop, array, merge

I'm using [preparse field plugin](https://github.com/aelvan/Preparse-Field-Craft) to [limit the amount of tags](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11749/limit-search-results-for-users-by-tag-and-limit-to-5-tags) a user can add to his account. I've modified the code slightly so the tags are processed as a `comma, separated, list`.

The plan is to integrate [Selectize](https://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) with the search form, so that users can choose from all available tags. As I can't use `relatedTo`, it'll have to involve some manipulation. I understand it isn't considered best practice to do this with Twig, but I'm not versed in PHP to build a plugin (I'm learning Python so Twig will have to do!).

The code below sets a variable to allow access to a merged array, I know [there's a similar post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5217/using-twig-to-merge-an-array-and-remove-duplicates) (I'd also like to avoid duplicates, but Selectize will ignore them anyway) but I'm struggling to follow that example and use it for my requirements.

Code below:

```
{% set users = craft.users.group('verified') %}
{% set merged = [] %}

{% for user in users %}
  {% set tags = user.tagsSpecialismSearchable %}
  {% set specialisms = tags|split(', ') %}

  {% for specialism in specialisms %}
    {# Merge the tag arrays #}
    {% set merged = specialisms|merge(specialisms) %}
  {% endfor %}

  <ul>
    {# Test the output #}
    {% for specialism in specialisms %}
      <li>{{specialism}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endfor %}

{# Output the merged array #}

<ul>
{% for mergedSpecialism in merged %}
  <li>{{ mergedSpecialism }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I know I'm setting `merged` in the wrong place, as all it outputs is a duplicate of the last `specialisms` array. So how would I loop through all users and output the available tags?

I'm probably missing some conditionals to check if the user has actually set tags, so any advice in layman's terms appreciated!

**Updated:** Working code (Thanks @kcolls)

```
{% set users = craft.users.group('verified') %}
{% set merged = [] %}

{% for user in users %}
  {% set tags = user.tagsSpecialismSearchable %}
  {% set specialisms = tags|split(', ') %}

  {% for specialism in specialisms %}
    {# Check if specialism already merged #}
    {% if specialism not in merged %}
      {# Merge each specialism #}
      {% set merged = merged|merge([specialism]) %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

  <ul>
    {# Test the output #}
    {% for specialism in specialisms %}
      <li>{{specialism}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endfor %}

{# Output the merged array #}

<ul style="background: blue; color: white;">
{% for mergedSpecialism in merged %}
  <li>{{ mergedSpecialism }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

[image]

For an added bonus, sort the array alphabetically:

```
<ul>
  {% for mergedSpecialism in merged|sort %}
    <li>{{ mergedSpecialism }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a typo in your merge, and the structure of the merge is incorrect.

```
{% set merged = specialisms|merge(specialisms) %}
```

This is saying set merged to the array specialisms merged with itself.

What I am guessing you want to do is merge each specialism into the merged array, which looks like this:

```
{% set merged = merged|merge(specialism) %}
```

Note that we are merging `specialism` and not `specialisms` (no s at the end).

I'm not sure what data type specialism is, but if it isn't an array, you may need to wrap it in square brackets. This would become:

```
{% set merged = merged|merge([specialism]) %}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Ah, of course! So it's basically similar to a simple `var += 1`, but with an array and a function. Problem is, I know enough to do some damage but not quite enough to get the solution! Actually, you could do away with the second loop as it is an array when I set `specialisms` (within the loop it's rendering strings). However, as I want to check each for a duplicate, I'd need the square brackets you mention, as well as an extra conditional (see my updated answer)